# how to add new key and value to dictionary, which is an attribute of a class object, in a loop in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object, attributes

I want to iterate through a loop in python and add new key&value to each attribute of an object. I tried implementing setattr() only to realize that I was just modifying the attribute, not adding new set of key and value.

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, price = None, units = None):
        if price is None:
            self.price = {}
        if units is None:
            self.units = {}


dates = ['10/20', '10/21', '10/22']
prices = [12.5, 12.7, 12.3] 
units = [100, 200, 300] 

cookie = Product()

for i in range(len(dates)):
    date = dates[i]
    price = prices[i]
    unit = units[i]
    data = [price, unit]
    keys = list(cookie.__dict__.keys())
    for attr, val in zip(keys, data):
        newD = {}
        newD[date] = val
        setattr(cookie, attr, newD) 
print(cookie.price)
print(cookie.units)
```

I want

```
    cookie.price = {'10/20': 12.5, '10/21': 12.7, '10/22': 12.3}
    cookie.units = {'10/20': 100, '10/21': 200, '10/22': 300}
```

as my result, but as I mentioned earlier, I get

```
    cookie.price = {'10/22': 12.3}
    cookie.units = {'10/22': 300}
```

Is there any way for me to append new set of key and value to each dictionary attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just focus on the for loop, since that part needs a change.
Everything else is good.

Looping through the list and getting the values is good.
The easiest way to update the data in your instance is just to call them.
In general, you add new values to a dictionary by simply calling

```
dic[new key] = new_value
```

With that, we can simply do this

```
for i in range(len(dates)):
    date = dates[i]
    price = prices[i]
    unit = units[i]

    cookie.price[date] = price
    cookie.units[date] = unit
```

Running this with the rest of the code the same returns

```
{'10/20': 12.5, '10/21': 12.7, '10/22': 12.3}
{'10/20': 100, '10/21': 200, '10/22': 300}
```

########################################################### 
UPDATE
##########################################################
If you want to add a lot of attributes and want a more general approach you could come at it from this angle.

I came up with some random attributes and added them to the class.

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, price = None, units = None,sold=None,bought=None,loc=None):
        if price is None:
            self.price = {}
        if units is None:
            self.units = {}
        if sold is None:
            self.sold = {}
        if bought is None:
            self.bought = {}
        if loc is None:
            self.loc = {}
```

I also gave them some random values

```
dates = ['10/20', '10/21', '10/22']
prices = [12.5, 12.7, 12.3] 
units = [100, 200, 300] 
solds = [10,20,30]
boughts = [100,200,300]
locs = ['san','cali','int']
```

Then we set up an instance of the class\

```
cookie = Product()
```

We also set up a list of all the attributes we're using\

```
attrs = ['price','units','sold','bought','loc']
```

We'll need this later to access all the attributes for our product.

Then we loop through and get our values setup:\

```
for i in range(len(dates)):
    date = dates[i]
    price = prices[i]
    unit = units[i]
    sold = solds[i]
    bought = boughts[i]
    loc = locs[i]
    values = [price,unit,sold,bought,loc]
```

Note, that it's important that the values list we create here has the same order as the attributes list above.
Also, note the lack of `date` in the list.

Now for the solution itself, we use `getattr`

```
    for z in range(len(attrs)):
    attr = attrs[z]
    value = values[z]
    
    getattr(cookie,attr)[date] = value
```

We loop through the list of attributes.
Now we use indexing to get the right values, which is why it's important to have the same order.

`getattr` is the same as doing class.attribute (e.g cookie.price).
We give it the right instance,and then the attribute name.
Then we use the same as in my original answer to set the new value.

Running this returns:\

```
{'10/20': 12.5, '10/21': 12.7, '10/22': 12.3}
{'10/20': 100, '10/21': 200, '10/22': 300}
{'10/20': 10, '10/21': 20, '10/22': 30}
{'10/20': 100, '10/21': 200, '10/22': 300}
{'10/20': 'san', '10/21': 'cali', '10/22': 'int'}
```

Here's all the code in one:\

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, price = None, units = None,sold=None,bought=None,loc=None):
        if price is None:
            self.price = {}
        if units is None:
            self.units = {}
        if sold is None:
            self.sold = {}
        if bought is None:
            self.bought = {}
        if loc is None:
            self.loc = {}

dates = ['10/20', '10/21', '10/22']
prices = [12.5, 12.7, 12.3] 
units = [100, 200, 300] 
solds = [10,20,30]
boughts = [100,200,300]
locs = ['san','cali','int']

attrs = ['price','units','sold','bought','loc']
cookie = Product()

for i in range(len(dates)):
    date = dates[i]
    price = prices[i]
    unit = units[i]
    sold = solds[i]
    bought = boughts[i]
    loc = locs[i]
    values = [price,unit,sold,bought,loc]
    
    for z in range(len(attrs)):
        attr = attrs[z]
        value = values[z]
        
        getattr(cookie,attr)[date] = value
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. The code I put here is the simplified version; I have like 10 attributes that I need to add data to and I don't want to write down every single one of them unless that's the only way to do it :(

Comment: Okay, I'll update my answer shortly, with an idea for a more general approach then.

Comment: my god, you are my saviorl. Thank you so much!! :DDD

Comment: No worries, just don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.